# Saving data in flat files using Mathematica

Tags: output

I am trying to solve a system $dx/dt =f (x, t)$ using the RK4 in Fortran 90 that works for any 2D Hamiltonian systems. I would like to generate using Mathematica a Fortran file .f90  that contains the terms (in FORTRAN SYNTAX) of the function $f(x, t)$ that corresponds to the right hand side of the RK4 solver. In the code it corresponds to the term `deriv`.

```
ndof = 2; ndim = 2*ndof;
Clear[h];
h = (1/2) (x[3]^2 + x[4]^2) + aa*x[1]^2/2 - bb*Sqrt[x[1]^2]^3/3 + 
 aa*x[2]^2/2 - bb*Sqrt[x[2]^2]^3/3 + aa*(x[1] - x[2])^2/2 - 
 bb*Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]^3/3;
derivq = Table[D[ h, x[i + ndof]]   , {i, 1, ndof}]
derivp = Table[-D[h, x[i]] , {i, 1, ndof}]
deriv  = Join[derivq, derivp]
filename = "1d_graphene_rk.f90"
$Output = filename; 
SetOptions[$Output]
Do[Print["dxdt(" <> ToString[i] <> ")=" <> 
    ToString[FortranForm[FullSimplify[deriv[[i]]]]]];, {i, 1, ndim}]
$Output = OutputStream["stdout", 1];
SetOptions[$Output]
```

it produces the following errors when trying to save `deriv`

```
Print::noopen: Cannot open 1d_graphene_rk.f90.
Print::noopen: Cannot open 1d_graphene_rk.f90.
Print::noopen: Cannot open 1d_graphene_rk.f90.
General::stop: Further output of Print::noopen will be suppressed 
 during this calculation.
```

How can I fix this code for it to work?

Comment: Try `$Output = OpenWrite["1d_graphene_rk.f90"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Export["test.f90", 
 Table["dxdt(" <> ToString[i] <> ")=" <> 
   ToString[FortranForm[FullSimplify[deriv[[i]]]]], {i, 
   ndim}], "Text"]

FilePrint["test.f90"]
```

> [image]

aside you may want to add `Assumptions -> Element[{x[1], x[2]}, Reals]` to `Simplify` ( that will turn `Sqrt[x[1]^2]` to `Abs[x[1]]` )

note if you really want to do "low level" file i/o you should work with `Write` , `WriteString` etc instead of messing with `Print` / `$Output`

Comment: Running the command as it is on the post, I am getting the following error `OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open /test.f90.`  '$Failed`.  What is happening on my notebook :-( :-( ?

Comment: oh you may be running in a directory where you do not have write permission.  Do use `SetDirectory` to set to somplace you can write or give a full path name to the file.

Comment: Great, many thanks. It works fine now.